# Filter Table using VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets. In worksheets("Dashboard") I have a dropdown list based on a table in worksheets("yearly View"). I am trying to filter this table based on the value in the drop down list in worksheets("Dashboard").

The code I have created is failing.

The drop down list in worksheets("Dashboard") is location in Range("AL1"). The column to be filtered is on worksheets("Yearly View").Range("P3").

Please see my code below:

```
Sub Filter_Table()
     Worksheets("Yearly View").Range("P3").Select
     Worksheets("Yearly View").Range("$P$3:$AR$24").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
     Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("AL1")
     ActiveSheet.Range("$P$3:$AR$24").AutoFilter Field:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this dropdown you mention from Data Validation or a Form listbox or even an ActiveX listbox?

Comment: Remove the last line of code. You basically filter than unfilter again with that last line. Also, the first line can be removed as well. it's erroneous.

Comment: @Xabier Its in Data Validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the code below under the Worksheet_Change on the Sheet "worksheets("Dashboard")" then the value of the listbox will be used to filter the Field 3 in this case on the Sheet "Yearly View":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$AL$1" Then
Worksheets("Yearly View").ListObjects("YourTableName").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Target.Value 'change the name of your table here. and the field value to the column number to be filtered on your table
End If
End Sub
```